# Finding equivalence class for $R_L$ of a regular language

Tags: equivalence-relations, regular-language, regular-expressions

Let $\Sigma = \{ a, b, c\}$,
$$
L = \{w\in\Sigma^*\mid w \text{ starts with $ab$ and ends with $ab$}\},
$$ i.e. $L = ab(\varepsilon + (a+b)^*ab)=ab+ab(a+b)^*ab$. I need to find a regular expression for each of the equivalence classes for $R_L$ and find a word, $w\in\Sigma^*$, to differentiate between the classes.

I found the following classes

1. $S_1 = (b + c)(a + b + c)^* + a(a + c)(a + b + c)^*$
2. $S_2 = ab(a + b + c)^*a$
3. $S_3 = ab(a + b + c)^*(bb + c)$
4. $S_4 = ab$
5. $S_5 = ab(a + b + c)^*ab$

$S_1$ have all the words that cannot be in $L$ so any $w\in\Sigma^*$ will suffice as for any $x\in S_1$, $xw\not\in L$.

For $S_2$ and $S_3$/$S_4$/$S_5$ the word, $w=b$, differentiates because for each $x\in S_2$, $y\in S_3\cup S_4 \cup S_5$, $xw\in L$ but $yb\not \in L$.

For $S_3$ the word $w=\varepsilon$ differentiates it from $S_4$/$S_5$.

Now I have two problems I haven't figured out yet:

1. $S_4$ and $S_5$ seems to be equivalent
2. where does $\varepsilon$ go

For the first problem it seems that they are indeed equivalent, because for each $w\in\Sigma^*$ and $x\in S_4$, $y\in S_5$, $xw\in L \iff yw\in L$, though I'm not sure because all the examples I have with similar languages where $L = u+v$ ($u, v$ regular expressiosn), put $u$ and $v$ in separate  equivalence classes.

As for the second problem, I'm not sure what to do, I can find $w$ such that $\varepsilon$ isn't part of any of the equivalence classes ($w=ab$ for $S_1$, $w=b$ for $S_2$, and $w=cab$ for $S_3$/$S_4$/$S_5$), but then I have an equivalence class with only $\varepsilon$